# jQuery ajaxs CORS request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nginx, cors

I am calling jQuery ajax request, at CORS resourse. Backend works on nginx, and there set OPTIONS hook and response with allowed all domains, and all request types. But unfortunatly i am getting error calback. On Chrome Network console i saw 204 answer on OPTIONS request. And I have never seen my original POST request.

```
var email = $('#your_email').val();
var sendData = {
    issue: {
        description: "email:" + email,
        category_id: 1
    }
};

$.ajax({
    url: "https://domen/issues.json",
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("goodtry:goodtryq"));
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(sendData),

    success: function (val) {
        alert("Thanks you, we are going to contact you soon");
    },
    error: function (val) {
        alert("Please check your internet connection");
    }
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's showing no content in response header. did you handled that in your backend code.

Comment: just a quick check set "dataType" as json

Comment: The 204 status is the problem I think, try returning 200 for the OPTIONS request and see if POST gets sent

Comment: @Akki619 json data type doesn't help.

Comment: @charlietfl 204 isn't problem, because i've change it to 200, and get same situation

Comment: ok, ive got message in console Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is solved. I missed diagnostic message

```
Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

So helpful answer culd be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24556330/2835239

Comment: If someone else has this issue, I've found that a lot of browsers report this message when the request has any problems with it, even not related to CORS. This was my case when I came across this page.